# Django - call celery Task from view

Tags: python, django, task, celery

i want to call a celery task from my views.py but for some reason i get the following error:

...

tasks.py

...

urls.py

```
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: At what url do you access the view when this error occurs? Is the pk not None / does the user really exist? It doesn't seem that you have a problem with celery task (yet, it may refuse to accept the user as argument due to serialization required), but with the query for user.

Comment: can you please be more specific im quite new to programming and im not really sure what you mean. If i remove the pk i get "Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 0):

Your `user = get_user_model.objects.get(pk=pk)` line should be changed to `user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=pk)`. `get_user_model` is a method which returns the default user model for the project. `get_user_model` method will not be called until you put the function parentheses after it (like `get_user_model()`).

Comment: Hello, many thanks for this hint :) sadly this does not fix the whole issue.
I updated my post accordingly

Comment: Please read the comment by @mfrackowiak for your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the pk of the user in the url, so it is always `None` and the user with `pk=None` doesn't exists. You should add the pk to the url, like `url(r'^user/wallet_deposit/new_addr_btc/(?P<pk>\d+)$', MyProject_Accounts.wallet_deposit_gen_new_addr_btc, name='wallet_deposit_gen_new_addr_btc')`. Also a user should be able to arrive at the correct url (you should generate the links correctly).
Maybe, as a user, I should be able to change only my account? If so, you should take the authenticated user from the request, as you did in the else block

Comment: now i got the following error:
NoReverseMatch at /user/wallet_deposit
Reverse for 'wallet_deposit_gen_new_addr_btc' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/wallet_deposit/new_addr_btc/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

im right that you have written (<pk>\d+)$' wrong at your answere ? ^^

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed and matched django 1.x and django 2.x syntax :). But I think only one slash is sufficient `(?P<pk>\d+)`. As I mentioned before
"Also a user should be able to arrive at the correct url (you should generate the links correctly). "
I mean that when you reverse the url, you should care about the pk to pass as argument. How are you reversing the url?

Comment: seems i not doing this, anyway i have no clue how to accomplish that here :(

Comment: If you are past the url directly in the url bar, you should add the pk at the and, like so http://localhost:8000/user/wallet_deposit/new_addr_btc/1/ if exists a user with `pk=1`, in other case you should put a pk of an existing user. Have you think about the using of the authenticated user `request.user` instead of passing the `pk` in the url?

Comment: That seem to work but now i get: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable

 user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        allocate_new_btc_address.delay(user)

Comment: That because you have JSON as serialziation type for celery, and the user object is not JSON serializable. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-serializer Although you can use other serializations type, it's a bad practice pass in model instance, because the tasks are async, it's possible that when the task is executed the instance in the db is changed. So you should pass the pk and fetch a fresh instance in the task. `allocate_new_btc_address.delay(user.pk)`
`@app.task
def allocate_new_btc_address(user_pk):
 user=User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)`

Comment: Seems that was a good idea. I get back a btc address and celery seems to exec the task. I didn't change the celery settings yet but for some reason the field at my DB "acc_btc_addr" does not get updated.

I will also updated my post accordingly -> update: post/question again edited

Comment: And the next question is @Fran what is the most useful CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER methode i could use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188146/discussion-between-fran-and-venom).